# How to leverage an existing commit for raising a PR?

Tags: git

I am working on `master`. I did `git commit`. I tried to `push` and I got to know that I am not allowed in master. Instead, I need to raise a PR.

I can obviously do this by creating a new branch, and **AGAIN** making changes and then creating PR. but how can I leverage the 1st commit I've made?

[0] `$git commit -m "committing is fun" myfile.js`

```
$git push
ERROR:Permission to xyz.git denied to *username*
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I asked around and got to know that I need to raise a PR and my senior will merge it. How can I leverage the commit[0] made earlier?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cherry-pick`.

Cherry picking in git means to choose a commit from one branch and apply it onto another.

You can do this by:

```
git checkout new-branch

git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

Now your commit from master has come to your new branch from where you want to raise a PR.

Just push to your new branch and raise PR.

Answer (score 1):

You can create branch out of commit using

`git checkout -b branchname <commit>`

and use the branch for pull request

Comment: <commit> means the commit id like this - dd2ts32h

am i getting it right?